# Android Training: Taking photos simply

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Maybe it's a compatibility issue or I'm missing something, but the example code for `PhotoIntentActivity` in the ["Taking photos simply"-tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) isn't working for me. 
When I take a big picture, the function `handleBigCameraPhoto()` never actually sets the image, because the private member `mCurrentPhotoPath` gets always set to `null` when `onActivityResult()` is called.

Is this just a problem with my Regza Tablet? What's an appropriate way to fix this?

Comment: post your log from logcat and exception trace..

Comment: There is no exception because the code checks if mCUrrentPhotoPath is null, so setPic() never gets called -> the taken photo doesn't get displayed as is should be (the small picture does get displayed because it uses a different function).

Comment: post your code for getting path of photo taken.. There is a chance that you are doing some mistake while getting path of photo..

Comment: It's a tutorial, the whole code is available at: http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/PhotoIntentActivity.zip

Comment: the tutorial itself has a fail in it - that is the tutorial site uses different code than the full example project. if you're using code from the tutorial page then you need to change mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath(); to mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem using the same tutorial for my app and discovered a possible cause of getting the null value: your activity is probably killed by the system due to lack of memory once you launch the camera app, so when your activity is restored all your member variables are not initialize.

An aproppiate way to fix it would be restoring to the previous state implementing **the following methods:**

1.- onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)

2.- onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)

Comment: I tried the tutorial again to see whether this could have been causing it, but now it's working normally!
But even if the activity had been killed, the tutorial already includes saving and restoring the mCurrentPhotoPath, so it must have been something else. I still have no idea what though!